# Unity: Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I'm new in Unity and C# and I'm doing some very simple exercises to understand.
The following code is for instantiate a variable number o cubes (clones of an already defined cube) in a Random position. For example, if I set numOfCubes=1, it should spawn 1 cube.

```
public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    public int numOfCubes;
    private GameObject[] clones;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        clones=new GameObject[numOfCubes];
        for(int i=0; i<numOfCubes; i++){
            Vector3 v=new Vector3(Random.Range(-10,10),Random.Range(-10,10),Random.Range(-10,10));
            clones[i]=Instantiate(cube,v,transform.rotation);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The problem is that the cycle goes in loop (if a set numOfCubes=x, infinite cubes spawns).
[image: This is the Script Component]

Comment: It looks correct to me.  Can you be more specific about how it is failing?

Comment: The script 'Script' is it attached on your 'Cube' prefab object or is it attached into a 'manager' game object?

Comment: I solved it using prefab cube. Thank you!